# Не декодируется файл из base64. Java. Windows

Tags: java, windows, base64

Не декодируется файл jpg из base64 на windows, хотя кодируется все прекрасно. На linux все работает. Вместо jpg на выхлопе получается файл типа .file, если открыть его через блокнот, то появляются непонятные символы, как если бы была проблема в кодировке.
Вот метод:

```
private void decodeImage(String imageString, String savePath) throws IOException {
        byte data[] = Base64.getDecoder().decode(imageString);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(savePath);
        fos.write(data);
        fos.close();
    }
```

Comment: А зачем вы картинку открываете блокнотом?

Comment: В том-то и дело, что это не картинка. Пишет, что неизвестный тип файла

Comment: Все вопросы к Винде, и к тому кто передал такое странное имя файла